# Refactor recursive algorithm into an iterative one?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have following recursive algorithm needed to redactor into iterative process.
**CvSeq** is a tree structure.Where **contour->h_next** gives the next node in the same level.
**contour->v_next** gives the next contour in level below.(child node)

```
void helperParseCurves(CvSeq* contour, int level) {

    if(contour->h_next != NULL) {
        helperParseCurves(contour->h_next, level);
    }
    if(contour->v_next != NULL) {
        helperParseCurves(contour->v_next, level+1);
    }

    //Process the nodes in contour
    for(int i=0; i<contour->total; i++){        
        CvPoint* p = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint, contour, i);
        //Paint the point p
    }

}
```

I want to refactor this logic into iterative algorithm.
Any tips on this?

Comment: Where would you start? What have you tried, and why are you having problems?

Comment: Do you have a member h_previous and v_previous?

Comment: General question: "how do I replace recursion with iteration?" answer "use a stack data structure".  Sometimes there are simpler answers than this (e.g. using a loop instead of recursion), but it depends on the complexity of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To traverse nodes w/o recursion you will need stack for saving previous states. *[Recursion is actually using of stack as well...]* :

```
struct StackData
{
 CvSeq* contour;
 int level;
 int traversed;
};

const int traversed_l = (1 << 0);
const int traversed_r = (1 << 1);

const int stack_size = 50; // should be at leas max depth
StackData stack[stack_size];
int stack_p = 0;

void helperParseCurves(CvSeq* contour, int level) {

    int traversed = 0;

    while(contour)
    {
       if(contour->h_next != NULL && !(traversed & traversed_l)) { // down to left
        assert(stack_p < stack_size);                             // and save current state
        traversed |= traversed_l;
        stack[stack_p].contour = contour;
        stack[stack_p].level = level;
        stack[stack_p].traversed = traversed;
        ++stack_p;
        contour = contour->h_next;
        traversed = 0;
        continue;
        }

       if(contour->h_next != NULL  && !(traversed & traversed_r)) { // down to right
        assert(stack_p < stack_p);                             // and save current state
        traversed |= traversed_r;
        stack[stack_p].contour = contour;
        stack[stack_p].level = level;
        stack[stack_p].traversed = traversed;
        ++stack_p;
        contour = contour->v_next;
        level = level+1;
        traversed = 0;
        continue;
       }


       //Process the nodes in contour
       for(int i=0; i<contour->total; i++){      
            CvPoint* p = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint, contour, i);
            //Paint the point p
       }

       // move up because either left and right nodes are NULL or already traversed
       if(!stack_p) break; // we are at the top
       contour = stack[stack_p].contour;
       level = stack[stack_p].level;
       traversed = stack[stack_p].traversed;
       --stack_p;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you forgot 'continue' at the end of the 1st 'if' statement.

Answer (score 1):

Have an empty vector/array/queue of CvSeq*'s. Have an index/pointer into it, at first pointing to its beginning (where the very first element will be).

Start with the tree's root and add its h_next and v_next to the vector.

Then while the index is less than the number of pointers in the vector - 1, take vector[index]'s h_next and v_next, add them at the end of the vector and do ++index.

You end up with pointers to all tree nodes in that vector/array/whatever.

Then you just iterate over it, painting things and whatnot.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Conceptually it's easy, but yes, there's a better way to do this.

Comment: If I had more info about cvesq it would be easier to go on... but regardless, the most compact way would be to either use pre-existing or else add h_prevous and v_previous, then iterate to the end and walk backwards without having to store a single thing.

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi: it's a tree, what sense would make h_previous and v_previous members to it? Are supposing to store necessary information in nodes themselves instead of a separate stack?